# How to directly modify strings within LuaJIT Bytecode?

Tags: lua, bytecode, luajit, bytecode-manipulation

I found out from my earlier questions in regards to editing bytecode through reddit and other forums, as well as from what I heard from my peers in discord, that decompiling and recompiling code would only lead to more problems than it solves, and that the better approach around this is to edit the bytecode directly through code.

That said, I don't know as to how do I go about this. With the idea in mind, I decided to go on a searching spree in regards to the process, to little results. I could only find some libraries, some idea, and barely any documentation or mention of the process in regards to loading, editing, and saving into the actual bytecode.

I need to know how do I go about this so that I can go on from there to create the necessary components for the program.

I was planning to use this knowledge to make the function to load LuaJIT bytecode, before editing specific strings from the code. After the changes are saved, I have to save the bytecode directly back into LuaJIT bytecode.

Any help and suggestions in regards to this is appreciated.

Comment: In other words, you are searching for a library to parse/modify LJ bytecode?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That and the process in regards to how to do so.

Comment: Also, any suggestions in regards to editing and saving the bytecode?

Comment: Anyone? Does anyone want to give it a go?

Comment: You may try to ask for such library on luajit mailing list.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Yeah... I got the reference to a library called LuaJIT lang toolkit. And I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Sure you need to edit bytecode instead of lua source? If it's simple string replacement, why not a simple search and replace?

Comment: @Real Would that work in the bytecode? Because I may also need to find and replace variables that contain string variables. Though optional, I may need to find a way to do just that.

Though if I have to go for the simple string replacement, how do I open and save in bytecode?